# Diagnosing a performance issue

Tags: java, performance, multidimensional-array, rust

I'm not very experienced with Rust and I'm trying to diagnose a performance problem.  Below there is a pretty fast Java code (runs in 7 seconds) and what I think should the the equivalent Rust code.  However, the Rust code runs very slowly (yes, I compiled it with `--release` as well), and it also appears to overflow.  Changing `i32` to `i64` just pushes the overflow later, but it still happens.  I suspect there is some bug in what I wrote, but after staring at the problem for a long time, I decided to ask for help.

```java
public class Blah {

    static final int N = 100;
    static final int K = 50;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //initialize S
        int[] S = new int[N];
        for (int n = 1; n <= N; n++) S[n-1] = n*n;

        // compute maxsum and minsum
        int maxsum = 0;
        int minsum = 0;
        for (int n = 0; n < K; n++) {
            minsum += S[n];
            maxsum += S[N-n-1];
        }

        // initialize x and y
        int[][] x = new int[K+1][maxsum+1];
        int[][] y = new int[K+1][maxsum+1];
        y[0][0] = 1;

        // bottom-up DP over n
        for (int n = 1; n <= N; n++) {
            x[0][0] = 1;
            for (int k = 1; k <= K; k++) {
                int e = S[n-1];
                for (int s = 0; s < e; s++) x[k][s] = y[k][s];
                for (int s = 0; s <= maxsum-e; s++) {
                    x[k][s+e] = y[k-1][s] + y[k][s+e];
                }
            }
            int[][] t = x;
            x = y;
            y = t;
        }

        // sum of unique K-subset sums
        int sum = 0;
        for (int s = minsum; s <= maxsum; s++) {
            if (y[K][s] == 1) sum += s;
        }
        System.out.println(sum);
    }

}
```

```rs
extern crate ndarray;

use ndarray::prelude::*;
use std::mem;

fn main() {
    let numbers: Vec<i32> = (1..101).map(|x| x * x).collect();

    let deg: usize = 50;

    let mut min_sum: usize = 0;
    for i in 0..deg {
        min_sum += numbers[i] as usize;
    }

    let mut max_sum: usize = 0;
    for i in deg..numbers.len() {
        max_sum += numbers[i] as usize;
    }

    // Make an array
    let mut x = OwnedArray::from_elem((deg + 1, max_sum + 1), 0i32);
    let mut y = OwnedArray::from_elem((deg + 1, max_sum + 1), 0i32);

    y[(0, 0)] = 1;

    for n in 1..numbers.len() + 1 {
        x[(0, 0)] = 1;
        println!("Completed step {} out of {}", n, numbers.len());
        for k in 1..deg + 1 {
            let e = numbers[n - 1] as usize;
            for s in 0..e {
                x[(k, s)] = y[(k, s)];
            }
            for s in 0..max_sum - e + 1 {
                x[(k, s + e)] = y[(k - 1, s)] + y[(k, s + e)];
            }
        }
        mem::swap(&mut x, &mut y);
    }

    let mut ans = 0;

    for s in min_sum..max_sum + 1 {
        if y[(deg, s)] == 1 {
            ans += s;
        }
    }

    println!("{}", ans);

}
```

Comment: 1) Are you sure this runs in around 7 seconds ? On my machine this runs in under 2 seconds.
2) There is no chance of any overflow here .. you are assigning values to your 2D array x from 2D array y which is full of 0s and never gets updated to anything else .. as a result, 2D array x has only 0s too .. what exactly are you trying to do here ? I don't see overflows..

Comment: @MostafaAli 1) What can I tell you, I have an old computer.  The 7 second time is for the Java program, the Rust program takes minutes to complete. 2) About the overflow.  The final answer is ~10^8 which is smaller than 2^31 - 1 = 2147483647.  Finally, you are wrong about the zeros.  The x and the y are not all zeros.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the bottom part of the code where you calculate the sum ...  ended up with some different logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To diagnose a performance issue in general, I:

1. Get a baseline time or rate. Preferably create a testcase that only takes a few seconds, as profilers tend to slow down the system a bit. You will also want to iterate frequently.
2. Compile in release mode with debugging symbols.
3. Run the code in a profiler. I'm on OS X so my main choice is Instruments, but I also use valgrind.
4. Find the hottest code path, think about why it's slow, try something, measure.

The last step is the hard part.

---

In your case, you have a separate implementation that you can use as your baseline. Comparing the two implementations, we can see that **your data structures differ**. In Java, you are building nested arrays, but in Rust you are using the ndarray crate. I know that crate has a good maintainer, but I personally don't know anything about the internals of it, or what use cases it best fits.

So I rewrote it with using the standard-library `Vec`.

The other thing I know is that direct array access isn't as fast as using an iterator. This is because array access needs to perform a bounds check, while iterators bake the bounds check into themselves. Many times this means using methods on `Iterator`.

The other change is to perform bulk data transfer when you can. Instead of copying element-by-element, move whole slices around, using methods like `copy_from_slice`.

With those changes the code looks like this (apologies for poor variable names, I'm sure you can come up with semantic names for them):

```
use std::mem;

const N: usize = 100;
const DEGREE: usize = 50;

fn main() {
    let numbers: Vec<_> = (1..N+1).map(|v| v*v).collect();

    let min_sum = numbers[..DEGREE].iter().fold(0, |a, &v| a + v as usize);
    let max_sum = numbers[DEGREE..].iter().fold(0, |a, &v| a + v as usize);

    // different data types for x and y!
    let mut x = vec![vec![0; max_sum+1]; DEGREE+1];
    let mut y = vec![vec![0; max_sum+1]; DEGREE+1];
    y[0][0] = 1;

    for &e in &numbers {
        let e2 = max_sum - e + 1;
        let e3 = e + e2;

        x[0][0] = 1;

        for k in 0..DEGREE {
            let current_x = &mut x[k+1];
            let prev_y = &y[k];
            let current_y = &y[k+1];

            // bulk copy
            current_x[0..e].copy_from_slice(&current_y[0..e]);

            // more bulk copy
            current_x[e..e3].copy_from_slice(&prev_y[0..e2]);

            // avoid array index
            for (x, y) in current_x[e..e3].iter_mut().zip(&current_y[e..e3]) {
                *x += *y;
            }
        }

        mem::swap(&mut x, &mut y);
    }

    let sum = y[DEGREE][min_sum..max_sum+1].iter().enumerate().filter(|&(_, &v)| v == 1).fold(0, |a, (i, _)| a + i + min_sum);

    println!("{}", sum);
    println!("{}", sum == 115039000);
}
```

- 2.060s - Rust 1.9.0
- 2.225s - Java 1.7.0_45-b18

On OS X 10.11.5 with a 2.3 GHz Intel Core i7.

I'm not experienced enough with Java to know what kinds of optimizations it can do automatically.

The biggest potential next step I see is to leverage SIMD instructions when performing the addition; it's pretty much exactly what SIMD is made for.

---

As [pointed out by Eli Friedman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522187/diagnosing-a-performance-issue/37527812?noredirect=1#comment62558314_37527812), avoiding array indexing by zipping [*isn't* currently the most performant way](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-zip-two-slices-efficiently/2048/13) of doing this.

With the changes below, the time is now **1.267s**.

```
let xx = &mut current_x[e..e3];
xx.copy_from_slice(&prev_y[0..e2]);

let yy = &current_y[e..e3];
for i in 0..(e3-e) {
    xx[i] += yy[i];
}
```

This generates assembly that appears to unroll the loop as well as using SIMD instructions:

```
+0x9b0    movdqu    -48(%rsi), %xmm0
+0x9b5    movdqu    -48(%rcx), %xmm1
+0x9ba    paddd     %xmm0, %xmm1
+0x9be    movdqu    %xmm1, -48(%rsi)
+0x9c3    movdqu    -32(%rsi), %xmm0
+0x9c8    movdqu    -32(%rcx), %xmm1
+0x9cd    paddd     %xmm0, %xmm1
+0x9d1    movdqu    %xmm1, -32(%rsi)
+0x9d6    movdqu    -16(%rsi), %xmm0
+0x9db    movdqu    -16(%rcx), %xmm1
+0x9e0    paddd     %xmm0, %xmm1
+0x9e4    movdqu    %xmm1, -16(%rsi)
+0x9e9    movdqu    (%rsi), %xmm0
+0x9ed    movdqu    (%rcx), %xmm1
+0x9f1    paddd     %xmm0, %xmm1
+0x9f5    movdqu    %xmm1, (%rsi)
+0x9f9    addq      $64, %rcx
+0x9fd    addq      $64, %rsi
+0xa01    addq      $-16, %rdx
+0xa05    jne       "slow::main+0x9b0"
```

Comment: As it turns out, using explicit array indexing is actually faster in this case; see https://users.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-zip-two-slices-efficiently/2048/13 for discussion of why.